# Can Emacs provide a wide scrollbar (birds-eye view) of code?

Tags: frames, fonts, scroll-bars

Microsoft Visual Studio has a very useful wide scrollbar where you get to see the whole file scaled so it fits vertically.  Is there a way to do this in Emacs?

[image: Wide scrollbar]

I've looked into having a 2nd frame and changing the zoom of the font in that frame, but the zoom affects any frame with the same buffer.

Comment: This mode could be helpful https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/HideShow. It could hide or show block of code based on the brackets.

Comment: Are you by chance looking at the minimap?  https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/MiniMap

Comment: @lawlist Yes, 'minimap' is what I'm after, thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Most of the emacs packages I've seen related to this have thought of it as coming from the sublime Minimap, which seems identical. I've seen people refer to these, but I don't have much experience with them:

- https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/MiniMap
- https://github.com/zk-phi/sublimity

Answer (score 1):

Library [**`thumb-frm.el`**](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/thumb-frm.el) gives you **thumbnail frames**, which provide a very similar feature.

These are real, usable frames, but they are thumbnail-size (configurable). And you can, if you want, have them placed along a screen edge, similar to what you show.

See Emacs-Wiki page [Fisheye with Thumbs](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/FisheyeWithThumbs) for details and screenshots.